# revising log files

Tags: logs

I am checking the log on a server multiple times throughout the day.  Each time, I open the log in NotePad++ and search for key words such as "warn" or "error" and then review the error or warning to determine my next course of action.  Instead of checking it multiple times a day, is there a way to run a script to check the log for errors or warnings?

Comment: would you please provide an example of the log file! and the commands you used

Comment: Not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Can you just use grep to find lines containing the warning error keywords? If you're using a more complex log format, you need to describe it. Then people can give you a sed or Python based script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

using CRON or AT you can set up a schedule to run a script or program according to any desired schedule such as at specific times repeated every day or once per week.

Look up linux CRON,  and `crontab -e`

as well as linux AT  https://linux.die.net/man/1/at

As for a script or program to be run, that would be up to you to implement.  Does not need to be complex, simply do a word search within specific log file, if found then do something.

that something can be send an email saying found, or just create a text file with either "NOT FOUND" or "FOUND {with detail}"

you would want to learn BASH shell scripting.

first thing that comes to mind is in linux `grep -l "word_pattern" filename`

if the `grep` command does not find your word pattern within the file, then it returns nothing and that can be used within a BASH shell script as your *not found* condition.

Comment: Thank you.  That was very helpful.  I apologize as I should clarify that my attempt was to use BASH and make it as basic as possible.   I was asked if I could write a bash script that would check the log for errors, and return a well-defined error message (if there were errors).  Then another team could call that script using one of their other monitoring agents, and alert based on that.  I don't know if that helps or makes any sense.

Comment: you were fine with **" Instead of checking it multiple times a day, is there a way to run a script to check the log for errors or warnings?"**.  If people are going to be so high strung to flag and  down vote questions like this then just close down this Unix section.